# GitKraken integration with GitLab with university login

Tags: git, gitlab, gitkraken

I would like to integrate my **GitLab** account with **GitKraken** through the *Preferences>Authentication>Connect* to GitLab feature in GitKraken. However this redirects to *GitLab.com* and my GitLab account is provided through my unversity at *gitlab.tubit.tu-berlin.de*. Using my university credentials at *gitlab.com* doesn't work and I can't figure out how to integrate the version of GitLab available through my university with GitKraken. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on that URL, I strongly suspect that your university is using a self-hosted instance of GitLab. [According to their Twitter account](https://twitter.com/GitKraken/status/840282496122068994), as of **March 10, 2017**, GitKraken does not support self-hosted GitLab instances.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

GitKraken has added this feature in [v.3.3.0](https://support.gitkraken.com/release-notes/current) in their Pro and EE version. You will need to provide your self-hosted GitLab URL and create a personal access token. You can check here how to add your GitLab self-hosted: https://support.gitkraken.com/integrations/gitlab-self-hosted.

Judging from your URL, I assume you are a student. You will get free access to GitKraken Pro through the [GitHub Student Developer Pack](https://education.github.com/pack).